# access a templatized nested class function and object in another class

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I have two header files.

one of the header files is ***tree.h*** which has a templatized class. It contains another class of "iterator" as well.

```
 template <typename Key, typename Value>
 class tree
 {
    public:
    class iterator
    {
       public:
       //...
       };
    iterator find(const Key& key) const;
    //....
    };
```

I have another header file of ***forest.h*** that in which the forest class inherits tree class from tree.h file.

```
 template<typename Key, typename Value>

 class forest : public tree<Key, Value>
 {
    //...
    //iterator find(const Key& k);  // overloading function 
    //iterator it;                  // an object of iterator 
    //...
 }
```

I need help with implementing the commented part of the code in forest class, however, I don't know how to do access tree's nested class stuff (because of templates). I tried doing it with typename but wasn't successful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
template <typename Key, typename Value>
class tree
{
public:
    class iterator {};
};

template <typename Key, typename Value>
class forest : public tree<Key, Value>
{
public:
    typedef typename tree<Key, Value>::iterator iterator;

    iterator find(const Key& k);
};

template <typename Key, typename Value>
typename forest<Key, Value>::iterator forest<Key, Value>::find(const Key& k)
{
    iterator it;
    return it;
}
```

C++11:

```
template <typename Key, typename Value>
auto forest<Key, Value>::find(const Key& k) -> iterator
{
    return {};
}
```